# CR10 - How to avoid "A date-time is required here." message

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to know how to get a 'blank' answer if there is no date present in the field to avoid the "A date-time is required here." error message.

I am using Crystal Syntax and here is what I have:

if {table.QuestionText} like "*Surgery Date*" then {table.Ans_Date}
else ???;

Any assistance to figure out the closing (???) of this formula would help. I've tried a few things but have had no success.

Thanks!

Comment: Try this: if {table.QuestionText} like "Surgery Date" then Cstr({table.Ans_Date}) else ""

Comment: Hey Andrew - That did it! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try converting the date to a String using the CStr function.  This will allow you to return a blank instead.

```
if {table.QuestionText} like "Surgery Date" then Cstr({table.Ans_Date}) else ""
```